# Digital or Analogue Backup Camera Signal?

Tags: backup-camera, tesla, dashcam

Is the Tesla Model S (2012-2016) rear backup camera send digital or analogue signal to the computer?

This part (Tesla Model S (2012-2016) BACKUP CAMERA (SEMCO)
1061269-00-D):

[image: Tesla Model S (2012-2016) BACKUP CAMERA (SEMCO) 1061269-00-D]

What type of connector is that?

The reason why I am asking is that I am hoping intercept the signal with a digital recording device, hopefully something small, a little box that lets analogue signal in, maybe amplifies it a little if digitization would weaken it, then outputs the same signal in a way that the same male plug would eventually connect back into the car's socket to receive the camera's picture.
If digital, that's probably trickier.

**I am looking to get any tips to the right hardware for the interception as well.**

Comment: This is going to need some very specialist knowledge to know the answer.  Do you have access to an oscilloscope?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the connector pins?

Comment: Agree with @HandyHowie - We need a picture of the pins in the connector.